# Google Gmail API - cannot load user email signature

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

i am using google gmail API for reading user email signature :

```
  public GenericEntry retrieveSettings(String username, String setting)
        throws IOException, ServiceException {
    URL singleUrl = new URL(BASE_URL + "emailsettings/2.0/" + domain + "/" + username + "/" + setting);
    return userService.getEntry(singleUrl, GenericEntry.class);
}
```

and then i am reading signature property like this :

```
      genericEntry.getProperty("signature");
```

After migration into last version of google client library line above returns always null. I noticed that signature is still returning in response but it`s in xmlBlob object.

I wonder why is this change happened and how i can parse xmlBlob object with the same encoding as getProperty method ?

Comment: May I ask how are getting the credential and using it with the service? I mean I have been looking at the Email Settings API but it seems to be outdated and deprecated. On the other hand, there is Java Client library as you seem to use but I do not find any similar methods in this library to Email Settings API. I mean, you seem to use GmailSettingsService as specified here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#java. All this is traduce to: I'm lost since like 2 weeks and I'm about to cry... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to parse XmlBlob to get data and remove http encoding.

Each time when we change version of Google client library we have to solve something, API is not stable at all.